# Mongo replica "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk"

Tags: mongodb

I have spent this week to make Mongo 4.4 PSA replica created by a freelancer to work. I gave up, deleted the complete mongod from all three servers and install from scratch following the [Mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). The only change was to create new db and import data before the replica initialization.

It failed for the first time (connection timeout) and I revisited my firewalls rules. Then it connected immediately and mongo shell refreshed on all nodes:

```
rs_bud:SECONDARY> show collections
rs_bud:PRIMARY> use bud
```

But when I perfom any operation on secondaries, they fail with `NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk` error.

```
rs_bud:SECONDARY> use bud
rs_bud:SECONDARY> show collections
uncaught exception: Error: listCollections failed: {
        "topologyVersion" : {
                "processId" : ObjectId("612bbc4940995c508859973a"),
                "counter" : NumberLong(4)
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1630258863, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "code" : 13435,
        "codeName" : "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1630258863, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
} :
```

I cannot find any logs useful to me:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:41.550+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23729,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"ServerPingMonitor is now monitoring host","attr":{"host":"10.0.0.4:27017","replicaSet":"rs_bud"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:41.550+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4333213, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM Topology Change","attr":{"replicaSet":"rs_bud","newTopologyDescription":"{ id: \"ad6bc985-50f4-4b01-9310-1457f8861f1f\", topologyType: \"ReplicaSetWithPrimary\", servers: { 10.0.0.2:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bbc4940995c508859973a'), counter: 4 }, roundTripTime: 504, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSSecondary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901549), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.4:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bba160d5e82841e5c8fc2'), counter: 6 }, roundTripTime: 1153, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSPrimary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, electionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001'), primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901550), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.5:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.5:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} } }, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, setName: \"rs_bud\", compatible: true, maxSetVersion: 1, maxElectionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001') }","previousTopologyDescription":"{ id: \"ad6bc985-50f4-4b01-9310-1457f8861f1f\", topologyType: \"ReplicaSetNoPrimary\", servers: { 10.0.0.2:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bbc4940995c508859973a'), counter: 4 }, roundTripTime: 504, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSSecondary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901549), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.4:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.5:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.5:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} } }, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, setName: \"rs_bud\", compatible: true }"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:41.550+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23729,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"ServerPingMonitor is now monitoring host","attr":{"host":"10.0.0.5:27017","replicaSet":"rs_bud"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:41.551+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4333213, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM Topology Change","attr":{"replicaSet":"rs_bud","newTopologyDescription":"{ id: \"ad6bc985-50f4-4b01-9310-1457f8861f1f\", topologyType: \"ReplicaSetWithPrimary\", servers: { 10.0.0.2:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bbc4940995c508859973a'), counter: 4 }, roundTripTime: 504, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSSecondary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901549), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.4:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bba160d5e82841e5c8fc2'), counter: 6 }, roundTripTime: 1153, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSPrimary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, electionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001'), primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901550), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.5:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.5:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bbc3d5c7d3123b83eedf8'), counter: 4 }, roundTripTime: 1468, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSSecondary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.5:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901550), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} } }, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, setName: \"rs_bud\", compatible: true, maxSetVersion: 1, maxElectionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001') }","previousTopologyDescription":"{ id: \"ad6bc985-50f4-4b01-9310-1457f8861f1f\", topologyType: \"ReplicaSetWithPrimary\", servers: { 10.0.0.2:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bbc4940995c508859973a'), counter: 4 }, roundTripTime: 504, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSSecondary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901549), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.4:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", topologyVersion: { processId: ObjectId('612bba160d5e82841e5c8fc2'), counter: 6 }, roundTripTime: 1153, lastWriteDate: new Date(1630258890000), opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1630258890, 1), t: 1 }, type: \"RSPrimary\", minWireVersion: 9, maxWireVersion: 9, me: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", setName: \"rs_bud\", setVersion: 1, electionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001'), primary: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", lastUpdateTime: new Date(1630258901550), logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, hosts: { 0: \"10.0.0.2:27017\", 1: \"10.0.0.4:27017\", 2: \"10.0.0.5:27017\" }, arbiters: {}, passives: {} }, 10.0.0.5:27017: { address: \"10.0.0.5:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} } }, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, setName: \"rs_bud\", compatible: true, maxSetVersion: 1, maxElectionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001') }"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:41.552+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20113,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Successfully connected to host","attr":{"connString":"10.0.0.4:27017","numOpenConns":1,"socketTimeoutSecs":0.0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:41.552+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20113,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Successfully connected to host","attr":{"connString":"10.0.0.4:27017","numOpenConns":2,"socketTimeoutSecs":0.0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-29T19:41:54.623+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1630258914:623411][1811:0x7f64db1aa700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1607, snapshot max: 1607 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (1630258896, 1) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (1630258901, 1) base write gen: 325"}}
```

and this looks OK too:

```
rs_bud:SECONDARY> rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   1483.0916013717651MB
log length start to end: 981secs (0.27hrs)
oplog first event time:  Sun Aug 29 2021 19:39:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)
oplog last event time:   Sun Aug 29 2021 19:56:03 GMT+0200 (CEST)
now:                     Sun Aug 29 2021 19:56:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

and

```
rs_bud:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs_bud",
        "date" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:58.119Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "term" : NumberLong(1),
        "syncSourceHost" : "10.0.0.4:27017",
        "syncSourceId" : 0,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
        "votingMembersCount" : 3,
        "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53.431Z"),
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53.431Z"),
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53.431Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53.431Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1630259801, 2),
        "electionParticipantMetrics" : {
                "votedForCandidate" : true,
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(1),
                "lastVoteDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:39:53.358Z"),
                "electionCandidateMemberId" : 0,
                "voteReason" : "",
                "lastAppliedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1630258782, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "maxAppliedOpTimeInSet" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1630258782, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "priorityAtElection" : 1,
                "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:39:53.386Z"),
                "newTermAppliedDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:39:54.485Z")
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "10.0.0.4:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 1035,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:57.415Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:57.901Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1630258793, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:39:53Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "configTerm" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "10.0.0.5:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 1035,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:57.417Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:57.431Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "10.0.0.4:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 0,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "configTerm" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "10.0.0.2:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 3617,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-08-29T17:56:53Z"),
                        "syncSourceHost" : "10.0.0.4:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 0,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "configTerm" : 1,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1630259813, 1)
}
```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Hmm, I have to read from primary only:
https://www.mongodbmanager.com/mongo-slaveok-error

Comment: In theory you should only ever write to primaries.  The secondaries are there for High Availability, not for load balancing or performance.  You should connect to the entire replica set, not just a node.  Also, stay away from arbiters, they can cause problems with some write concerns when a data bearing node has failed.

Comment: You can read from a secondary, but you never connect directly to the secondary.  Instead, connect to the entire replica set (using all hosts in the connection string) and set a read preference of secondary preferred - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-secondaryPreferred.  In practice I recommend you *always* read from the primary and never read from the secondary.  The reason is that a replica set is for High Availability, not scaling.  If you need more performance either scale vertically or shard out horizontally instead of leveraging the secondaries.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I would accept it as an answer. What I desperately tried was to connect the secondary via mongo shell directly. I wanted to check if data were synchronized to this node. Now i understand it was silly idea. The secondary is a part of the replica set and since that it does not operate on its own.

Comment: I thought that slaveOk=false means that the replica is not working correctly.

Comment: I found this great article: https://www.bmc.com/blogs/mongodb-replication/. To verify the replication on secondary: db.getMongo().setSecondaryOk() and then you can perform your queries.

Comment: Good article!  Connecting to a secondary directly (instead of the whole replica set) and issuing the command slaveOK = true allows the system to continue.  Its like an acknowledgement you are aware you are not connected to the replica set and not connected to the primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it was mentioned above, you can only read from secondaries and this behavior can be configured via [read-preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-secondaryPreferred) option (whether it's a good idea or no depends on your goals). However, you still can connect to the secondary directly if you set [directConnection=true](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/connection/#direct-connection), but you should clearly understand why you need this.

Answer (score 8):

```
rs.secondaryOk()
```

this command started the secondary in a cluster node & was able to run queries on mongo

Answer (score 1):

You need to "connect to the replica set". How to do this depends on the driver, e.g. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/reference/create-client/#replica-set-connection) for Ruby. When you do this the driver will route the operations to the correct server (e.g. all writes will be sent to the current primary).

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me, after adding the flag `readPreference=secondary` in the database connection.